# Check if password is incorrect when try to wifi connect on android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a code which I am using to connection with wifi:

```
override fun setupWifi(ssid: String, password: String) {
        try {
            val wifiConfig = WifiConfiguration()
            wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid)
            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password)

            val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
            val netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)
            wifiManager.disconnect()
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)
            wifiManager.reconnect()

            ReactiveNetwork
                    .observeNetworkConnectivity(applicationContext)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasState(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
                    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeBy(onNext = { connectivity ->
                        if (connectivity.available())
                            presenter.showActivationScreen()
                    }, onError = {
                        presenter.showPasswordError()
                        logger.e("wificonfigactivity", "wifi connection failed", it)
                    }, onComplete = {
                        logger.d("wificonfigactivity", "wifi connection failed")
                    })
                    .addTo(startStopDisposables)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            showError(getString(R.string.activation_wlan_error))
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a question - how can I check if user put wrong password?

Comment: Note that some of these `WifiManager` methods are defunct on Android Q.